# Sync without the middle layer

Tags: sqlserver

My company has uploaded data from the middle layer(SQL database) into salesforce. This is a one time upload. Now they have terminated the middle layer. Now they would like to keep sync between the salesforce and the data that is originated from. How is this possible without the middle layer?

Any insights would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With SQL there are multiple ways you can make real time sync

1)Using .NET framework expose data as a SOAP webservice and let salesforce outbound message or trigger invoke or consume the webservice

Recently salesforce has come up with lightning connect and I did a POC with SQL data exposed as OData

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.com/2015/01/lightning-connect-and-sql-integration_3.html

Note this is one way sync currently but it is real time .